# Meteor Template Helper Reactivity inconsistency

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a Template helper for showing schools with reactive var schoolFindQuery

```
    Template.schoolCompareCenterList.helpers({
  schools(){
    console.log("schoolFindQuery is :" + schoolFindQuery);
      let school =  Schools.find(JSON.parse(schoolFindQuery), {limit : 20});
      console.log("school count is : " + school.count());

        return school;
}
})
```

and schoolFindQuery reactive variable is changing with button clicks, with button clicks subscribtion is renewed and ui is changing accordingly. Odd thing is, when subscription return data there is no problem, but whenever subscription returns any data, after that Helper code will not rerun with subscription change (even i can see subscribtions with meteor toys) and ui is not showing any data.
My subscription code is below,

```
this.autorun(function() {


if(subscription)
  subscription.stop()


//This reactive variables set by buttons and by the ghelp of reactivty subscription rerun
    query = "{"
    if(_sTy__.get() != 0 && _sTy__ != null)
      query += "\"schoolType.schoolT\" : \"" +  _sTy__.get()+ "\","
    if (_sTy2__.get() != 0 && _sTy2__ != null)
      query += "\"schoolType.schoolTT\" : \""+  _sTy2__.get() +"\","
    if(regexSchoolName.get() != 0 && regexSchoolName.get() != null )
      query += "\"schoolName\" : {\"$regex\": \".*" + regexSchoolName.get() + ".*\", \"$options\": \"i\"},"

    query += "\"haveSchoolDetailInfo\" : true}"

    subscription = Meteor.subscribe("schoolCompare.infinite.publish", query,  20, 0);
    schoolFindQuery = query;})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure schoolFindQuery is reactive? It looks like a normal var; it should be set differently. Can you show how it's defined?

Comment: I defined it like var schoolFindQuery = new ReactiveVar(); it acts reactive until empty subscription

Comment: You don't change a reactive variable by assigning to it, but by using the `get()` and `set(newVal)` methods.

Comment: There was no difference between usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to look at this tutorial which explains Session variables, Reactive Dict and Reactive Var: https://blog.meteor.com/the-meteor-chef-reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables-971584515a27#.undr5c1f0

Comment: By using reactive variable specific to template solve the problem. Thanks for tutorial advice